# How to set Clonezilla to clone only a partition

Tags: partition, clonezilla

I have been trying to clone my Debian `/dev/sda1` partition containing `/root` with size of 100GB using Clonezilla. I did this by using Clonezilla-live to create `iso` file with size around 18 GB. It seems succesfully clone `/root`. My problem rises when I tried to restore it in virtualbox which I created with drive size of 110GB. The restore process shows the following:

```
Disk destinantion is too small!
Destination disk size: 230686720 sectors (118.1 GB)
Source disk size from the image: 976773168 sectors (500.1 GB)
Program terminated!!
```

It looks like Clonezilla only copies `/root`, but put the size of entire harddirsk instead of only 1 partition. Am I doing something wrong in creating iso file to restore 1 partition only? Or is it the limitation mentioned in Clonezilla [website](http://clonezilla.org/)? As far as I understand, it states that `The destination partition must be equal or larger than the source one` not `The destination disk`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73125/how-to-use-dd-to-clone-a-partition-off-a-disk-image?rq=1 Suppose you create in the VM a partition table containing the "size/filesystem type" properties as your current `/dev/sda1` that you already have. Then you could copy in there the `image_of_sda1.img` of your `/dev/sda` that you created with `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=./image_of_sda1.img". Be careful with `if=` (input file) and `of=` (output file), since it may erase your disk if you do it the other way around.

Comment: sounds like you did `savedisk` instead of `saveparts`.

Comment: @pidosaurus I haven't tried using `dd` to clone, but it seems interesting to try that since it doesn't require live boot like CloneZilla.
@meuh I perfectly remember I chose saveparts because I repeatedly tried the cloning more than twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to find the answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/568227/prepare-a-disk-to-be-imaged-by-clonezilla-for-use-on-smaller-disks) in which we can modify `image/sda-pt.parted` in image folder produced by cloning before the `iso` file is made to overcome this problem. The `sda-pt.parted` file contains the following:

```
Model: ATA ST31000524AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 976562500s
...
```

where the value in the second line can be converted to the size of the cloned disk (though I only wanted to clone partition) by `976562500*512 = 5E11 (500GB)`. Let say the size of partition that is desired to be clone (or could be only the actual size of file in that partition) is 40GB, then that value on the second line can be altered into `4E10 / 512 = 78125000s`, so the `sda-pt.parted` is going to be like this:

```
Model: ATA ST31000524AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 78125000s
...
```

As long as the new partition has equal size or larger to that value, then the cloning will work flawlessly.