# Access regular partitions inside an LVM logical volume

Tags: partition, lvm, partition-table

I have the following setup:

- /dev/sdX - disk (GPT table)
- /dev/sdX1 - regular partition
- /dev/sdX1/crypt - LUKS encrypted partition
- /dev/sdX1/crypt/lvm_vg - lvm volume group
- /dev/sdX1/crypt/lvm_vg/lvm_lv - lvm logical volume

Inside lvm_lv, there is a regular partition table (GPT) with two partitions, one EFI partition and one for the OS. lvm_lv and the partitions inside it are used by attaching lvm_lv to a KVM virtual machine.

How can I access the partitions inside lvm_lv without attaching it to a virtual machine? If I open crypt with cryptsetup, LVM detects lvm_vg.

This is a backup copy of another disk, you are wondering how this convoluted setup came to be.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73132/30851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73132/30851 .

- losetup --find --show --partscan --read-only /dev/lvm_vg/lvm_lv

  - This will output something like: /dev/loop0
  - Now we have /dev/loop0p1 and /dev/loop0p2 (partitions we were looking for)
- mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt